# What should be in the "misc-depends:" in a control file?

Tags: packaging

Lintian gives error without "misc-depends:" in the control file.

```
 W: brightness-controller source: debhelper-but-no-misc-depends brightness-controller
```

What should be supposed to be in it? Every else works fine without it.

Comment: I think you should read the [Debian New Maintainers' Guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html#control) before doing anything in packaging. In particular, `${misc:Depends}` is not a field, but a variable. Probably empty in your case.

Comment: I did the packaging. Now lintian spots error due to absence of these.

Comment: @muru I could not understand this. "Some debhelper commands may cause the generated package to depend on some additional packages. All such commands generate a list of required packages for each binary package. This list is used for substituting ${misc:Depends}."

Comment: @muru Ok, I have understood standards-version but not misc:depends

Comment: What's the actual lintian error you get? If you haven't used any complex debhelpers, `misc:depends` could be empty.

Comment: @muru I have edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"misc-depends" is not a field in the `debian/control` file, but infact a variable that `dh_gencontrol` will substitute during the build of the binary package. As [the New Maintainer's Guide says](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html#control):

> Some debhelper commands may cause the generated package to depend on
>   some additional packages. All such commands generate a list of
>   required packages for each binary package. This list is used for
>   substituting ${misc:Depends}.

In practice, it looks like:

```
Depends: libfoobar, ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
```